# Azure text-to-speech changes volume and inflection after a number of days for the same request

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

Azure text-to-speech, using Japanese neural audio (ja-JP-NanamiNeural), leveraged by REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech

However, especially noticeable in recent months, the exact same request sometimes returns different volume and inflection from the previous output results.
Sometimes it feels as if a completely different person is speaking.

For example, if you input "いかがだったかしら？" ("How was it?" in English) in Japanese returns the upper voice as of February 2023, but the lower voice in July 2023.

February 2023

https://stackcheck.web.fc2.com/2023-02-voice.mp3

July 2023

https://stackcheck.web.fc2.com/2023-07-voice.mp3

It is Japanese, but you can see that the volume and inflection are all completely different.

Furthermore, there is no inflection even though it is in the interrogative form, and the accuracy seems to have deteriorated greatly.

The request was made using PHP's cURL.
Of course, the source code was not changed between the two voices.

```
$your_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$url = 'https://japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken';
$aryHeader = [
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: '.$your_key,
    'Host: japaneast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length: 0',
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aryHeader);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$token = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
file_put_contents('/file/token', $token);

$url = 'https://japaneast.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1';
$aryHeader = [
    'Authorization: '.$token,
    'Content-type: application/ssml+xml',
    'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3',
    'Host: japaneast.tts.speech.microsoft.com',
    'User-Agent: example',
];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aryHeader);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$aryPost = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='ja-JP'>
    <voice xml:lang='ja-JP' xml:gender='Female' name='ja-JP-NanamiNeural'>
        <prosody rate='60%'>いかがだったかしら？</prosody>
    </voice>
</speak>";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aryPost);
$audio = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Since I use text-to-speech as a guide for my characters, I am very troubled by the fact that the inflection and volume change without my permission, and moreover, the inflection, etc. keeps updating in an unnatural way.
Therefore, I would like to specify a specific version for stable output, but I don't know how to do that at the moment.
If you have a solution or have had a similar problem and solved it, please let us know.

There are these two types of Japanese endpoints, and by switching from west to east, the forced change was temporarily suppressed, but after a period of time, the output results became common with west.
Japan East https://japaneast.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1
Japan West https://japanwest.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1

Comment: Can you provide your code in the question?

Comment: Thank you.
I added the source code and added the audio comparison.

Comment: Sorry, the audio file was incorrect and has been corrected.